# I have upgraded from yeoman 1.3.4 to 1.4.0 and I cannot import mystrings.d.ts

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, typescript

I have a file mystrings.d.ts  which contains :-

```
  declare interface IReactSearchBoxStrings {
  PropertyPaneSearchOptions: string;
  BasicGroupName: string;
  DefaultSearchResultsPageUrlFieldLabel: string;
  EnableCustomSearchPlaceholderLabel: string;
  SearchLabel: string;
  CustomSearchPlaceholderModeOnAlert: string;
}


declare module 'reactSearchBoxStrings' {
  const strings: IReactSearchBoxStrings;
  export = strings;
}
```

I want to import the contents thus into ReactSearchBoxWebPart.ts:-

```
import * as strings from 'reactSearchBoxStrings';
```

It complies but when I want to ship it  (gulp bundle --ship) I get this error :-

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'reactSearchBoxStrings' in 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/SPFx/Projects/1-4-0/react-search-box-webpart/lib/webparts/reactSearchBox'
resolve 'reactSearchBoxStrings' in 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/SPFx/Projects/1-4-0/react-search-box-webpart/lib/webparts/reactSearchBox'
```

This worked Ok when the project was built with yeoman 1.3.4, but does not work when the project is built with yeoman 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding reference path over the import statement. Like below:

```
/// <reference path="..." />
import * as strings from 'reactSearchBoxStrings';
```

Sometimes Typescript is unable to resolve the relative path for the modules. In these cases reference path helps.

Comment: I tried this and got this message from typescript 2.4.2 :-

[ts-npm-lint] Removed reference to 'loc/mystrings.d.ts' in lib\webparts\reactSearchBox\ReactSearchBoxWebPart.d.ts

then got error [webpack] 'dist' 

followed by module not found

Answer (score 0):

This is due to yeoman 1.4.0 using TypeScript 2.4.2 which starts to phase out .d.ts and @Typings.

So to fix rename "MyStrings.d.ts" to IReactSearchBoxStrings,ts.  Change the contents to

```
export interface IReactSearchBoxStrings {
  PropertyPaneSearchOptions: string;
  BasicGroupName: string;
  DefaultSearchResultsPageUrlFieldLabel: string;
  EnableCustomSearchPlaceholderLabel: string;
  SearchLabel: string;
  CustomSearchPlaceholderModeOnAlert: string;
}
```

In the calling file change :-

```
import * as strings from reactSearchBoxStrings
```

to

```
import { IReactSearchBoxStrings} from './components/IReactSearchBoxStrings';
```

and finally add

```
var strings: IReactSearchBoxStrings;
```

to the calling file.

Then it all compiles and links.